# A comic about a girl traveling in bizzare techno organic landspace

Tags: story-identification, comics

Help identify title of a comic with a girl protagonist looking for a cure for a deadly disease that turn human into monsters. the whole comic story is filled with strange combination of tech and organic matters.

some clues :
- It is never stated clearly if the girl experiencing real world or dream world. In subsequent part of the series the girl knowingly enter a virtual world but at the first titles she was in some kind of bizzare reality of everyday world with strange fleshy monsters mutated from human beings..

- It is considered R18+ for the drawings and some part of the storyline
- At the end of the series , the girl and the spacecraft that saved the girl , jumped in to empty part of the universe , so far away from known universe that there's no star visible.
- Virtual Reality , Time dilation , Dreamscape , all reoccuring theme and it is almost impossible to know the reality unless it is speficically stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is the [Drunna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Druuna) comic, "Mandragora", by Paolo Eleuteri Serpieri.

[This review](https://www.goodreads.com/review/show/1720492687?book_show_action=true) has some pictured pages from the comic and a confused description:

> I really can't explain what this comic is about. Apparently this is just book #5. It's kind of the hot dream of a hetero male in a sci-fi world. Mandragora has sex, lots of sex, with humans and with no humans, with men and with women, consented or dub-non-con. I admit some scenes were pretty hot, although most of it made little to no sense to me.

(I've censored the image slightly)

[image: Druuna speaking to a mechano-organic computer man]

Be aware it is not a comic for kids; it is an adult comic.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SF:F! Do you think you could elaborate more on why you think your answer is correct? Things that might help would be talking about how the story elements from the question line up with the elements from the story in your answer, talking about the general plot, etc.